# Qml Canvas Animation Error

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I have this qml file implemented into one of my main window files. However, the animation isnt showing. I copied this from a textbook tutorial on canvas animations so I was confident there would be no foreseeable errors in syntax. There are no errors when I debug, but I cannot see any part of the animation. Any ideas?

HeartBeat.qml

```
Canvas{
id: canvas
visible: true

width: 600
height: 300

property int lineWidth: 2
property var points: []
property real arg: -Math.PI

Timer{
    interval: 10
    repeat: true
    running: true
    onTriggered: {
        arg += Math.PI/180
        while(arg >= Math.PI) arg -= 2*Math.PI
    }
}

onArgChanged: {
    points.push(func(arg))
    points = points.slice(-canvas.width)
    canvas.requestPaint()
}

function func(argument){
    var a=(2*Math.PI/10); var b=4*Math/5
    return Math.sin(20*argument) * (
                Math.exp(-Math.pow(argument/a, 2)) +
                Math.exp(-Math.pow((argument-b)/a,2)) +
                Math.exp(-Math.pow((argument+b)/a, 2))
                )
}

onPaint:{
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    ctx.reset()
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    var pointsToDraw = points.slice(-canvas.width)
    ctx.translate(0, canvas.height/2)
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(0, -pointsToDraw[0]*canvas.height/2)
    for(var i=1; i<pointsToDraw.length; i++)
        ctx.lineTo(i, -pointsToDraw[i]*canvas.height/2)
    ctx.lineWidth = canvas.lineWidth
    ctx.stroke()
}
}
```

Main.qml

```
Item{
    id: container
    x: 530
    y: 542
    width: 600
    height: 300
HeartBeat{
    id: heartBeatMonitor
}
}
```

I have no problem with other canvas animations... it is just this animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding logging is a good idea for early debugging.

`onArgChanged: {
    points.push(func(arg))
    points = points.slice(-canvas.width)
    console.log(points);
    canvas.requestPaint()
}`

After that I see that array is filled by a lot of NaN. Then I looked at `var b=4*Math/5` and it seems a few letters are missng after `Math`. I don't know what was expected to be printed there.

Man, you should find better textbook!

Comment: Thank you. The problem ended up being the var b=4*Math/5, when changed is b=4*Math.PI/5 and gives the correct animation. This textbook is very bare bones and assumes JavaScript experience which is annoying to someone who has always worked with c++.

Comment: The textbook for some reason never discusses logging which is SO important after seeing this!